# ASP.NET Controls won't align properly

Tags: asp.net, css, controls, panel, alignment

-- Occurs in IE8.0.7600.16385

-- Does NOT occur in Chrome

I have a formatting problem. Been banging my head against the desk all day long. For the life of me, I can't figure out why my Reset and Search buttons aren't aligned (Search button is raised, Reset button is lowered). Seems to work great when I run from debug, but once I publish they're crooked as politicians. Here's the image:

[image]

Here's the rendered code:

```
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
           <td class="cssPanelWidth">
               Search String:&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="UpdatePanel1">

               <div id="Panel1" class="cssPanelWidth" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'lbSearch')">
    <input name="txtSearch" type="text" id="txtSearch" />&nbsp;<a onclick="javascript:Search();" id="lbSearch" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lbSearch','')" style="display:inline-block;width:75px;text-decoration:none;height:16px;font-size:Small;font-family:Tahoma;color:White;border-style:Solid;border-color:#20548E;background-color:#20548E;"><center>Search</center></a>
</div>
</div>

           </td><td class="cssBottomLeftAlign">
               <div id="TestIt"><a id="lbResetReasons" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lbResetReasons','')" style="display:inline-block;width:75px;text-decoration:none;height:16px;font-size:Small;font-family:Tahoma;color:White;border-style:Solid;border-color:#20548E;background-color:#20548E;"><center>Reset</center></a></div>

           </td><td class="cssBottomRightAlign">
               <div id="UpdatePanel2">

               <a onclick="javascript:SendSelectedItems();" id="lbSelect" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lbSelect','')" style="display:inline-block;width:75px;text-decoration:none;height:16px;font-size:Small;font-family:Tahoma;color:White;border-style:Solid;border-color:#20548E;background-color:#20548E;"><center>Select</center></a>
               <a onclick="javascript:CloseMe();" id="lbCancel" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lbCancel','')" style="display:inline-block;width:75px;text-decoration:none;height:16px;font-size:Small;font-family:Tahoma;color:White;border-style:Solid;border-color:#20548E;background-color:#20548E;"><center>Cancel</center></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

And the css stuff (just in case):

```
<style type="text/css"> 

    .cssBottomRightAlign
    {
        text-align: right;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    .cssBottomLeftAlign
    {
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    .cssPanelWidth
    {
        width: 240px;   
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

</style>
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?!?! Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks,
Jason

EDIT: aspx code just in case --

```
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
           <td class="cssPanelWidth">
               Search String:&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>            
               <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" class="cssPanelWidth" DefaultButton="lbSearch" runat="server"><asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSearch" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Underline="False" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Tahoma" BackColor="#20548E" ForeColor="White" Height="16px" Width="75px" BorderColor="#20548E" runat="server"><center>Search</center></asp:LinkButton></asp:Panel></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>

           </td><td class="cssBottomLeftAlign">
               <div id="TestIt"><asp:LinkButton ID="lbResetReasons" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Underline="False" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Tahoma" BackColor="#20548E" ForeColor="White" Height="16px" Width="75px" BorderColor="#20548E" runat="server"><center>Reset</center></asp:LinkButton></div>

           </td><td class="cssBottomRightAlign">
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSelect" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Underline="False" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Tahoma" BackColor="#20548E" ForeColor="White" Height="16px" Width="75px" BorderColor="#20548E" runat="server"><center>Select</center></asp:LinkButton>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Underline="False" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Tahoma" BackColor="#20548E" ForeColor="White" Height="16px" Width="75px" BorderColor="#20548E" runat="server"><center>Cancel</center></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
           </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: I assumed you were using Safari from what the window looked like in the screenshot. Whereas in actual fact, you're using IE8 without the status bar. How can you survive without the status bar? :o

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. I removed my answer because it wasn't the solution (or even in the ballpark) :)

Comment: Wow man, the S.O. Nazis are on the rampage again. Since when is a displayed formatting issue "too localized" or "not applicable to a worldwide audience"???

Comment: Probably because "I forgot to add a CSS class to my `div`" is not going to help anyone in the future. Just saying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, right click the offending button and "Inspect Element".  It will tell you everything that contributes to the element's style and hopefully the answer will pop out at you.  Other browsers have similar features.

Comment: Thanks for that -- it lead to the answer. Come to find out, panels get their own <div> tags, and although the Reset button was in a <div> tag, it didn't have it's css class set. Thanks!